# Migrations Table Empty - Can't run php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

So, I've copied a database off a server that I'm working on and I've just started working on it. However for some reason the migrations table is empty so when I try to run `php artisan migrate` it can't because it doesn't know that all the tables are already created. Is there a quick way of fixing this rather then adding in the name of every migration to the table manually as there are a lot of migrations in this project?

Thanks.

Comment: You should re-run your all migrations. Is importing the database from another really important? In development, you should be relying on seeders if you need to have the data. Connecting to an empty/fresh database and running `php artisan migrate` should create the migrations tablet itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **work around** it the following way:

1. Create another empty database.
2. Switch your application to use the new database.
3. Run **php artisan migrate**
4. Copy **migrations** table from new database to the old one
5. Switch your application to use the old database again.

You could also delete existing migration files (bad idea) or move them to some other folder so that **migrate** command doesn't see them.

You could also fill the table yourself, but that seems pretty time consuming.

Why is that table empty in the first place? Is it empty on your server as well?

Comment: I figured this work around out too after a while. I honestly have no idea why the migrations table is empty. I started working on the site and it was empty on the server. Previous dev didn't seem all that great based on some other work done on the site.